# strtotime() does not return correct value when specifying date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: php, date-format

I want to convert date `24/09/2010` in format `dd/mm/yyyy` to `2010-09-24` in format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

This works:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("09/24/2010"));
```

But this does not:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("24/09/2010")); // it returns '1970-01-01'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` does its best to guess what you mean when given a string, but it can't handle all date formats. In you example, it is probably thinking that you are trying to refer to the 24th month, which isn't valid, and returns 0, which date then treats as the unix epoch (the date you got).

you can get around this using the [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) and [explode()](http://php.net/explode) functions, like so:

```
$date = "24/09/2010";
$dateArr = explode("/",$date);
$timeStamp = mktime(0,0,0,$dateArr[1],$dateArr[0],$dateArr[2]);
$newFormat = date("Y-m-d",$timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

according to php, the valid php formats are stated [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). So basically what you gave is invalid.

Alternatively, you can use [mktime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), [date_parse_from_format](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) or [date_create_from_format](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, 
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("09/24/2010"))
will work,because the date format--"09/24/2010"is correct,
but "24/09/2010" is not the correct date format.
you can find something useful [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)