# strtotime function return 01/01/70 with valid input

Tags: php, date

I have a valid date from a database column with varchar type, all in d/m/y format. Then when I try to convert it into a date format with strtotime function and date formating I get 01/01/70. I have even tried to replace the database result with plain string values. 
I have searched and found this links 
[PHP strtotime returns a 1970 date when date column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737363/php-strtotime-returns-a-1970-date-when-date-column-is-null)
[PHP : strtotime() returns always 01/01/1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946457/php-strtotime-returns-always-01-01-1970)
[strtotime() does not return correct value when specifying date in dd/mm/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809501/strtotime-does-not-return-correct-value-when-specifying-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-for)
but both were not helpful since the data is not null and it is in valid format. Here is a snippet of my code

```
if(isset($item['prep_date']) && $item['prep_date'] != NULL){
    $trial=$item['prep_date'];
    echo ": ".$trial;
    $prepDate= strtotime($trial);
    $prepDate = date('d/m/y', $prepDate);
    echo "= ".$prepDate;
}
```

What am i missing? Here is the result of the two echoes

```
28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 03/01/13= 01/03/13: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 18/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 02/09/13= 09/02/13: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 05/11/13= 11/05/13: 28/10/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 05/11/13= 11/05/13: 28/10/13= 01/01/70: 28/10/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 05/11/13= 11/05/13: 11/12/13= 12/11/13: 11/12/13= 12/11/13: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 11/12/13= 12/11/13: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 28/11/13= 01/01/70: 30/01/14= 01/01/70
```

Comment: can you please echo or var_dump($item['prep_date']) and post the result?

Comment: `28/11/13` is treated as `11th day of 28th month` (and it's surpising for me that it wasn't obvious for you from the `03/01/13= 01/03/13` result). If you want the `day month year` order - use dot, not slash

Comment: yes, using a 4 digit year is a really good habit also

Comment: @zerkms I specifically gave d/m/y to specify the 28th day of 11th month. How is that possible

Comment: @altsyset: I'm not getting it. "strtotime function return 01/01/70 with valid input" --- is incorrect, there is no 28th month (on this planet). "I specifically gave d/m/y to specify the 28th day of 11th month" --- nope, you're doing it for **FORMATTING**, **AFTER** parsing

Comment: @zerkms I will give it a shot with a dot

Comment: @altsyset: also try to read your code once again and realize that `date` is performed **AFTER** `strtotime`

Comment: if you have php 5.2 try http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: @zerkms that does it...thanks man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your get value of year 1970 because your `strtotime()` returned `false`:

```
var_dump( strtotime('28/11/13') ); # false
```

Take a look at [supported date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). `strtotime` asumes this is american month, day and year (`mm/dd/yyyy`), like it states [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If inputed format is `dd/mm/yyyy` then the easiest method would be to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or `strtotime` on `str_replace('/', '.', 'dd/mm/yyyy');` to make it european date format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: op's is 2 digit year, will DateTime still handle it OK?

Comment: @Ryan: it will even handle 1 digit. See [standard format for american format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). Description = `American month, day and year`; format = `mm "/" dd "/" y`; examples = `"12/22/78", "1/17/2006", "1/17/6"`.

Comment: this is even simpler solution